# Physical mechanisms for true depolarization of light (decrease in the degree of polarization)

Tags: optics, polarization

I understand that complex polarization transformations (e.g., in Mie scattering) can occur without changing the technical degree of polarization (P). I'm interested in the mechanisms that specifically reduce P, leading to a genuine mixture of polarization states or even unpolarized light.

I'm working with Stokes parameters to study light-sample interactions. Can anyone explain the physical processes that cause true depolarization and how these processes are reflected in the changes to the Stokes parameters? Specific references for further reading on this topic would be greatly appreciated.